# Redirect after enter form react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have a form in react, actually I can make it work with a **submit button.**
When I click on the submit button, **a Link send me to the desired component.**

But when I press "**enter**" after writing something in my input form, like most people do, **nothing happen indeed.**

How can I redirect to the results page when someone write something in the form and press enter key?

Here is the form, and his functional component with useState:

```
function Header(){

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!title) return;
        setTitle(title);
        setTitle("");
        console.log(title);
    }

    return(
        <nav>
            <li className="liensNav">
                <Link className="lien" to="/">
                    {/* Tu as fill white dans le logo svg */}
                    <img className="logo" src={logo} alt="logo"></img>
                </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="liensNav">
                <Link className="lien" to="/">Top Games</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="liensNav">
                <Link className="lien" to="/top-streams">Top Live Streams</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="liensNav">

                <form className="formSubmit" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                    <input className="inputRecherche" type="text" value={title}
                    required onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />


                <button type="submit">
                    <Link
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/resultats",
                        state: {
                            id : title
                        }
                    }}
                    >
                        <img className="logoLoupe" src={search} alt="icone loupe"/>
                    </Link>
                </button>


                </form>

            </li>

        </nav>
    )
}
export default Header;
```

Maybe I need to use **onKeyPress** ? **But anyway I don't know how to redirect on enter, that is the major problem.**

Thanks if someone if passing by.

Comment: Put the Link on the outside and then wrap the button inside of it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you would need onKeyPress or onKeyUp, in its handler you can check for enter like this
and use history to redirect to the page

```
handleKeyDown(e) {
 if (e.key === 'Enter') {
  history.push('/resultats')
 }
}
```

you input

```
<input className="inputRecherche" type="text" value={title}
                onKeyPress={(e) => this.handleKeyDown(e)}
                required onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if a specific value exists, if so then redirect.

```
if(title) {
  // redirect or whatever....
}
```

React-router-dom has a nifty redirect component.